# Python Request/cURL to C# POST request

Tags: c#, python, curl, post

I need help with simple POST request to discussion forum. I have right datas, it works in Python also when I write as cURL command and run it with GitBash. Problem is that's not work in C#.

I need help from you, because I don't know how write right code in C#, which i need.

Here is a Python code:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Cookie': 'cookie_notice=1'
}

data = 'id=44&typ=0&parent=-1&login=User&password=password&text=test22\ntest33'

response = requests.post('address.php', headers=headers, data=data)
```

Here is a cURL:

```
curl 'address.php' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'Cookie: cookie_notice=1' -d "id=44&typ=0&parent=-1&login=User&heslo=password&text=test22"
```

I've try compile with this: https://curl.olsh.me/

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "http://address.php/"))
    {
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Cookie", "cookie_notice=1"); 

        request.Content = new StringContent("id=44&typ=0&parent=-1&login=User&heslo=password&text=test22", Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 

        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
    }
}
```

The program runs this C# code without any errors, but in discussion forum isn't my contribution.

Thanks for the Answer !

Comment: What part doesn't work in c#, are you trying to convert the python to c#? consume the response? Can you provide us some more info so we can help.

Comment: What does the C# code output?

Comment: I update my question and add C# code.

Comment: You need to compare requests on HTTP level to see any discrepancies. It may even be the server reacting differently to a different `User-Agent`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `HttpClient` ignores request `Cookie` header because it relies on `HttpClientHandler` and its `CookieContainer`. The solution is telling `HttpClient` that you will set cookies via headers

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { UseCookies = false }))
```